# React Native: Is it possible to have custom subviews within a TextInput component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, textinput

I’m trying to create a TextInput component that has a custom view when someone’s name is typed. So for example, if the name was John, it would search for that string and add a view with John’s profile image and his name inline with the text. Currently, when I put a view as a child of the TextInput component nothing shows up. That being said children with only Text components do show up.

I have tried rendering various types of containers and elements in the TextInput components, but all of the above do not show up in the render.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have anything but text in a TextInput. I would try wrapping an Image component and a TextInput component in a row-aligned View.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: "row", width: "100%", borderWidth: 1}}>
    <Image style={{height: 30, width: 30}} source={require("./your/image.path")}/>
    <TextInput style={{width: "75%"}}/>
</View>
```